# Can't get Sitecore JobMonitor/JobContext to show dialogs

Tags: sitecore

According to [this blog post by Adam Najmanowicz](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2013/05/16/how-sitecore-powershell-got-gui-support-a-tale-of-jobmonitor-and-sitecore-async-ui-api/), it should be relatively easy to open an alert or confirm dialog from a background job using the JobMonitor and JobContext classes in Sitecore.Jobs.AsyncUI.  I can't get it to work.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  The CodeBeside class for my control is below.  I've tried opening it as both a modal dialog and an application, but it does not show either alert.

```
public class JobMonitorTestForm : BaseForm
{
    protected JobMonitor Monitor;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (this.Monitor == null)
        {
            if (!Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
            {
                this.Monitor = new JobMonitor { ID = "Monitor" };
                Context.ClientPage.Controls.Add(this.Monitor);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Monitor = Context.ClientPage.FindControl("Monitor") as JobMonitor;
            }
        }

        this.Monitor.JobFinished += this.JobFinished;
        this.Monitor.JobDisappeared += this.JobFinished;

        this.Monitor.Start("JobMonitorTest", "Test", this.Run);
    }

    private void JobFinished(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        SheerResponse.Alert("Job finished!");
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        JobContext.Alert("Hello!");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

**Update**

I found another clue, but I'm still at a loss.  My log file is showing the following exception.  It's a null reference exception in the constructor of Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage because HttpContext.Current is null.  That makes some sense since the call was initiated from a background thread, but I thought the whole point of the classes in the AsyncUI namespace was to work around this issue.

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 23:18:28 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage..ctor()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.SheerResponse.Alert(String text, String[] arguments)
   at TestApp.sitecore.shell.Applications.Dialogs.JobMonitorTest.JobMonitorTestForm.Run() in c:\Projects\sc66Test\TestApp\TestApp\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\JobMonitorTest\JobMonitorTestForm.cs:line 45
   at Sitecore.Jobs.AsyncUI.JobMonitor.TaskRunner.Run()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use threading? There really is absolutely no reason for you to use threads on ASP.

Comment: @Aron - there is a very valid reason in Sitecore's context - Ben needs to provide user's interaction while a background task is happening. Also he is not using threads per-se, rather Sitecore Backgroung Jobs manager.

Comment: Okay. But for ANY of this to make sense, the user HttpContext will have gone out of scope well before you try to find "Monitor".

Comment: @Aron - That's the point of the Monitor control and async UI library in Sitecore - it's implemented in a way that it pings the server periodically for any actions that occurred in background jobs that could result in user interaction so you can provide rich Desktop-like experience. It's very Sitecore specific topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small problem with the code you posted, that - like anything in the async UI caused a great deal of investigation :)

The problem is that of timing. You cannot perform your job creation in OnLoad since that would engage the monitor before the request had time to round-trip to the user and be handled by the monitor control in the browser. Basically the Job has nothing to hold on to yet.

There are 2 ways around it. You can show your dialog and as a user to press a button/ribbon/menu which would trigger an event to start the job. The other approach is what I did in [PowerShell Extensions](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/) when I wanted the runner to start the job without user intervention. In the Sheer control include a JavaScript that posts an event to your dialog once the page has loaded:

```
window.onload=function(){
    scForm.postRequest("", "", "", "psr:execute");
};
```

and then in your control's Code Beside:

```
[HandleMessage("psr:execute", true)]
protected virtual void Execute(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    // Do the Job starting through the monitor.
}
```

Hope that helps. If you have any problems with it I would be more than happy to share more details or provide a sample

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam.  This was a great help.